# Strip decimals in SSRS expression without rounding

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

In my report I'm trying to remove the decimals without rounding. I'll be using this to set the minimum value in the vertical axis of the area chart.

So I tried `=Format(98.56, "N0")`, but this returns *99*, which is incorrect. It should return *98*.

I've been searching specifically for SSRS, but most of the results are for tsql.

My question: How can I remov decimals in SSRS without rounding?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using "Floor". It effective rounds down to the nearest integer. You'll find this under the Math functions.

```
=Floor(Fields!Number.Value)
```

Note, there's also a Floor function in Transact-SQL that works the same way in case you need to do some of the processing in your SQL script.

**Update based on request in comments**
If you wanted to achieve the same result after the decimal point, all you need is a little algebra.

```
=Floor((Fields!Number.Value*10))/10
```

That should turn 99.46 into 99.4.  Given that it shaves off the remainder, you could then tack on any additional zeroes you wanted.

Comment: Thanks. Would you know how I can round down to the nearest decimal place? For example, 99.46 would be rounded down to 99.40

Comment: I edited my answer to solve that question as well. If it all works for you, please mark as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up converting to Int. The following expression in SSRS returns **98**:

```
=Int(98.56)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is quite old, but as I ended up here having the same question I would like to share my answer:

While FLOOR and CEILING are fine if you take extra measures to handle numbers <0 or know they are always >=0, the easiest way to simply strip off the decimals is to use

```
=Fix(Fields!Number.Value)
```

FIX only returns the integer part of a number, without any rounding or transformation. For negative numbers Int rounds up.

Source: [Examples for Fix, Floor and Ceiling](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4027/sql-server-reporting-services-unknown-but-useful-functions/)

Source: [Difference between Int and Fix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/int-fix-functions)